# 400 Errors on Github Pages because of error on manifest.json being read as text/html

Tags: json, reactjs, github-pages

So I'm trying to serve my github pages website to https://dgatto.github.io/website/ and i keep getting these errors

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 ()
manifest.json:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 ()
manifest.json:1 Manifest: Line: 1, column: 1, Syntax error.

I think that the 400's are because of the "syntax error" and I'm pretty sure that the syntax error is because of the manifest.json file being read as text/html in the [network tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CzDzN.png).

My question is, how do I change the server to accept the file as json? It's github pages so I don't really have access to the server itself.

Here's the repo if that helps: https://github.com/dgatto/website

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are serving your Application at https://dgatto.github.io/website/, you should define it as the `homepage` in your `package.json` file and then build.

Comment: Works now! Much thanks :D

I originally brought this code over from another repo that used a different domain name, and it still had the old url. Thank you very much :)